# Help with if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying this part of my script and it work perfectly

```
if win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1] == 65567:
```

but when I'm trying to add this

```
win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2] == categoriesScreenPos[1]:
```

it stop working... why?

The `categoriesScreenPos[1]` is the same value `(17,242)` of the position of the cursor, but the if doesn't work...

Full `if`:

```
if win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1] == 65567 and win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2] == categoriesScreenPos[1]:
```

What I'm trying is to, when the cursor is in a specified position and has a specified icon, the if break a while.

ps: if I print the both commands like this

```
print categoriesScreenPos[1]
print win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2]
```

they give me the same result!

edit: doesn't work because I have a break inside the if, and the while still continues... but only with the first if statement, worked perfectly.

I'm sorry...
Full part of the script:

```
while timer < timerMax:
        timer = timer + 1
        time.sleep(2)
        m_move(*categoriesScreenPos[1])
        time.sleep(2)
        m_move(*loginScreenPos[0])
        if win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1] == 65567 and win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2] == categoriesScreenPos[1]:
            print '[' + time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')+'] ' + 'Login Sucess'
            break
        if win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1] == 65541:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            kbShell.SendKeys('{F2}')
            print '[' + time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')+'] ' + 'Login Failed'
            break
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What do you expect to happen? What does actually happen?

Comment: try to use a print('something') inside the `if` to see if the problem is with the `if` not taking the right side or after that

Comment: Please post __all__ the relevant code: the break, the while, all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `m_move(*loginScreenPos[0])` causes the mouse coordinates to change (because it moves the mouse) and consequently so does `win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[2]` -- you say you `print`ed it, but did you `print` it *immediately after* moving the mouse elsewhere?